# how to convert the date format from dd-mmm-yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am uploading the csv file. The csv file contains the date format in `dd-mm-yyyy` format. How can I change it to `yyyy-mm-dd` format. I also tried to_date function but it gives the error as invalid date.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by below code

```
require 'date'

date = DateTime.parse("22-02-2019")
formatted_date = date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

**output**

```
"2019-02-22"
```

please go through with this document https://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/Time:strftime you will find out the different formatting style